# Pick always a different number in a range of 3K numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, random

i'm builing an hybrid app in Javascript that casually pick an exercise from a database, wait for the user to solve it and then pick another exercise.

Nothing difficult at this point, my problem is about picking always a different exercise from database.

Now my code 'works' in this way:

> 1. Gets total number of exercises (about 3K),
> 2. Generate a N random number from 1 to 3000,
> 3. Pick the N exercise from DB,
> 4. Save the N number in the 'used' db table,
> 5. Generate another number name,
> 6. This time first of all check if the generated number was already used,
> 7. If NO pick exercise, if YES generate another number,
> 8. etc...

The code works well for the first 2000-2500 numbers, then start to be really slow because generating a random number not already used starts to be very difficult. When the number used are just a bit less than 3K the code is totally broken: continues to check but the new number never comes

How can i handle this situation in a fast and light way that use memory as less as possible?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

I'm using WebSQL in a phonegap application

That's what i'm doing (code):

Here i get the number of the exercises

```
1. SELECT COUNT(*) AS countArt FROM Exercises'
```

Here i pick a random number from 1 to totalNumberOfExercises

```
2. randomNumber = random(totalNumberOfExercises);
   function numeroCasuale(len){
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * len) + 0;
        return num;
    };
```

Here i check if my randomNumber is already in the DB, that means is already used

```
4. SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM alreadyUsed WHERE numero=randomNumber)
```

If randomNumber exists i generate another randomNumber and check it again and again...

Comment: Its better to generate an array out of all possible 3000 numbers, then delete the already used ones, and then get a random number from the remaining unused numbers

Comment: Put the numbers from 1 to 3000 into an array, then shuffle the array. Then you can just pick numbers by increasing an index into the array, and you're guaranteed not to get a duplicate.

Comment: How are you generating this random number (SQL or application)? What database are you using? Can you post some code?

Comment: @Pointy how do you shuffle the array?

Comment: Generate a random number between 1 to 3000. If the number has `not been previously` generated, mark that number has used. If the number was `used previously`, use the `next` number i.e ( random number + 1). If it is the last number in the index, go to the first number. In this way you will always arrive at a `unused` number. In order to **speed up** the process, you could **pre-calculate** the random numbers and store in table and simply fetch the next index in the table one after another.

Comment: The way you are doing it, think of the probability of a number from 1-3k falling in an ever shrinking set of usable values. @Pointy, that's a very stable solution! +1

Comment: I've updated question with code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this shuffle function from another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript):

```
function shuffle(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
}
```

You can create this:

```
function generateRandomSequence(amount){
    var random = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<amount; i++) random[i] = i;
    return shuffle(random);
}

var random = generateRandomSequence(3000);
var gamesCompleted = 0;

function nextGame(){
    console.log(random[gamesCompleted]);
    gamesCompleted++;
}

nextGame();
```

This creates an array where position 0 = 0, 1 = 1 and so on and shuffle it so we have a random sequence without doublicates. Keep track of how many games you have completed and use this number as the index for the next question. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsjnw7he/).

Comment: i think your answer is good, but my problem is that i need to permanently store the array of random numbers because the code needs to work inside a peonegap app and i want the picked exercise to be unique even if the user close the app

Comment: Aha. Well in that case, save it in local storage. Quick example, when the app starts check if `localStorage.getItem('randomSequence') == null` if true, generate the sequence and save it to localStorage, if false, get the item from there. You will need to use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`to store it as a string in localStorage. Don't forget to save and load the gamesCompleted amount it as well. Does that make sense? I can write up an example if you wish and add it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I know localStorage, I've just a question: isn't localStorage read/write quite "slow"?

Comment: It can be if you have a lot of data, and also note it's synchronous, which means your app will hang while the data is loading. I think you should test it out to see the impact. Save a date object to a variable and subtract it from another date object after loading and saving. Bottom line, you'll be writing the sequence once per install lifetime, and retrieving it every time a user opens the app (not from background). It's not bad in my opinion.

Comment: What about using WebSQL (that i'm already using)? Should be faster, or am i wrong?

Comment: I don't have experience with WebSQL, but if you're already using it, by all means keep doing that. Consistency is underated :)

Comment: Well, i will try to implement it! Thank you very much for your help! I will wait some days to see if there are others options and then i will accept the answer:)

Comment: Thanks! I'm using your code and it's working very well!!